# jQuery only loading the first component

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I'm trying to load the comments of an answer using jquery and API call to get the comments of a given answerid.
But I'm facing two problems:

- Only the first Comment button loads the comments. If I press the Comment button of a second answer, nothing happens.
- If I have two answers I can't get the comments of the first answer. I mean, If my question has only one answer I can print that answer comments but If I post a new answer, I can't get the comments of the first answer.

Do I need to give differents id's to my answer blocks? Something like `data-id {answer['answerid']}`?

Btw, my application API is in PHP.

```
<div class="qa-a-list-item hentry answer">
                                            {foreach $answers as $answer}
                                                {include file="answers.tpl"}
                                            {/foreach}
                                            <!-- END qa-a-item-main -->
                                        </div>
```

**answers.tpl**

```
<div class="qa-a-item-main">
    <div class="asker-detail clearfix">
        <div class="asker-avatar avatar"><a href="../user/admin">
                <img width="40"
                     height="40" class="qa-avatar-image" src="{$answer['user_photo']}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="user-info no-overflow">
            <h3 class="asker-name">
                {$answer['username']}
            </h3>
            <p class="asker-point">
                {$answer['answer_user_points']} points
            </p>
            <span class="title" style="background: #EEEEEE;">{$answer['role']}</span>
        </div>



        {include file="answers_partials/vote_panel.tpl"}
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="qa-a-selection">
            </div>
            <input name="code" type="hidden">
            <input name="qa_click" value="" type="hidden">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="a-item-inner-wrap">
        <div class="a-item-wrap">
            <div class="qa-a-item-content">
                <a name="187"></a><div class="entry-content">{$answer['body']}</div>
            </div>
            <span class="qa-a-item-meta">
                    answered
                    <span class="qa-a-item-when">
                        <span class="qa-a-item-when-data">
                            <span class="published">
                                <span class="value-title" title="">
                                </span>{$answer['creation_date']}</span></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="qa-a-item-who">
                        <span class="qa-a-item-who-pad">by</span>
                        <span class="qa-a-item-who-data">{$answer['username']}</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <div class="post-button clearfix">
                <div class="post-button clearfix">
                    <button class="btn icon-chat show-textarea" title="Add a comment on this answer" type="button" data-answer="{$answer['publicationid']}">Comment</button>
                    <div class="textarea">
                        {include file="comment_form.tpl"}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    answerid = {$answer['answerid']};
    console.log("Answerid" + answerid);

</script>
{HTML::script('comment.js')}
```

My javascript function:

```
$('.comment-form').hide();
var commentsFetched = false;

$("body").on("click", ".show-textarea", function(){
    if (commentsFetched) { // check the flag
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON("/controller/api/comments/comment.php", {
        answerid : answerid
    }, function (data) {
        console.log("AID " + answerid);
        console.log("Data" + data);
        commentsFetched = true;
        $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
            console.log("Comment:" + comment);
            $('.comment-form').append('<article class="tweet-data">' +
                '<div class="comment-items">' +
                '<div class="qa-c-list-item  hentry comment" id="c3574">' +
                '<div class="asker-avatar">' +
                '<a>' +
                '<img width="40" height="40" src="' +
                comment.user_photo +
                '"></a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="qa-c-wrap">' +
                '<div class="post-button">' +
                '<button name="" onclick="" class="btn icon-flag" title="Flag this comment as spam or inappropriate" type="submit">flag</button>' +
                '<button name="" class="btn icon-answers" title="Reply to this comment" type="submit">reply</button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<span class="qa-c-item-meta">' +
                'commented' +
                ' 1 day' +
                ' ago' +
                ' by ' +
                '<a style="display: inline" href="" class="qa-user-link url nickname">' +
                comment.username +
                '</a> ' +
                '<span class="qa-c-item-who-points"> ' +
                '<span class="qa-c-item-who-points-pad">(</span><span class="qa-c-item-who-points-data">140</span><span class="qa-c-item-who-points-pad"> points)</span> ' +
                '</span> ' +
                '</span> ' +
                '</span> ' +
                '<div class="qa-c-item-content" style="color: #2d2727; font-size: 13px"> ' +
                '<a name="3574"></a><div class="entry-content">' +
                comment.body +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div> <!-- END qa-c-item --> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div>');
        });
    });

    $('.comment-form').show();
});

$("body").on("click", ".textarea-ok, .textarea-cancel", function(){
    commentsFetched = false;
    $('.comment-form').hide();
});
```

Am I thinking this correctly? Why does this work only when I have one answer?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add IDs to your answer blocks.  Say you had

```
<button class="btn icon-chat show-textarea" title="Add a comment on this answer" type="button" data-answer="{$answer['publicationid']}" data-id="{$answer['id']}">Comment</button>
```

Then you could do

```
$("body").on("click", ".show-textarea", function(){
  var answerid = $(this).data('id');

  // this is the correct comment form
  var $commentForm = $(this).closest('.comment-form');

  if (commentsFetched) { // check the flag
    return;
  }
  $.getJSON("/controller/api/comments/comment.php", {
    answerid : answerid
  }, function (data) {
    console.log("AID " + answerid);
    console.log("Data" + data);
    commentsFetched = true;
    $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
        console.log("Comment:" + comment);
        // append to correct comment form
        $commentForm.append('<article class="tweet-data">' +
            '<div class="comment-items">' +
            '<div class="qa-c-list-item  hentry comment" id="c3574">' +
            '<div class="asker-avatar">' +
            '<a>' +
            '<img width="40" height="40" src="' +
            comment.user_photo +
            '"></a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="qa-c-wrap">' +
            '<div class="post-button">' +
            '<button name="" onclick="" class="btn icon-flag" title="Flag this comment as spam or inappropriate" type="submit">flag</button>' +
            '<button name="" class="btn icon-answers" title="Reply to this comment" type="submit">reply</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<span class="qa-c-item-meta">' +
            'commented' +
            ' 1 day' +
            ' ago' +
            ' by ' +
            '<a style="display: inline" href="" class="qa-user-link url nickname">' +
            comment.username +
            '</a> ' +
            '<span class="qa-c-item-who-points"> ' +
            '<span class="qa-c-item-who-points-pad">(</span><span class="qa-c-item-who-points-data">140</span><span class="qa-c-item-who-points-pad"> points)</span> ' +
            '</span> ' +
            '</span> ' +
            '</span> ' +
            '<div class="qa-c-item-content" style="color: #2d2727; font-size: 13px"> ' +
            '<a name="3574"></a><div class="entry-content">' +
            comment.body +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div> <!-- END qa-c-item --> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</div>');
    });
});
// show correct comment form
$commentForm.show();
});
```

FYI

```
$('.comment-form').show();
```

That shows all html elements with class='comment-form'.  Assuming there are multiple answers per page, that will show all the comment forms for each answer.

To target the comment form that is a direct ancestor of the button that was clicked to call the function, use:

```
$(this).closest('.comment-form').show();
```

Comment: It does not work, `<script>
    answerid = {$answer['answerid']};
    console.log("Answerid" + answerid);

</script>` I already have this where I get the answerIS and on my JS function I call the API using that.

Comment: Yeah but that answerid only gets set when the page loads and not in response to clicks

Comment: So you suggest to change that `answerid: answerid` to `answerid : answerID` considering I declare `var answerID = $(this).data('answer');` ?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, yes the property value in your getjson parameter 1 should be set to the contents of the answerId variable that's created in the click handler - or you can rename the variable in the click handler to answerid.

Comment: Well, but I don't think you're getting the problem straight. Your advice was helpful and thank you for that. But the main issue is about that `<div class="post-button clearfix">
                    <button class="btn icon-chat show-textarea" title="Add a comment on this answer" type="button" data-answer="{$answer['answerid']}">Comment</button>
                    <div class="textarea">
                        {include file="comment_form.tpl"}
                    </div>
                </div>`
because when I call the JS function by pressing "show-textarea".

Comment: `$("body").on("click", ".show-textarea",` I need this. Because the show-textarea should be unique for each answer, otherwise all the show-textarea will open no matter which answerid is sent.

Comment: Well you're doing `$('.comment-form).show()` which will show all elements with class='comment-form'.  You should do `$(this).closest('.comment-form').show()` instead.

Comment: That does not print anything at all @James

Comment: Isn't there anything that I can do like:
`$("body").on("click", ".show-textarea" + answerid, `
`<button class="btn icon-chat show-textarea {answer['answerid']}" title="Add a comment on this answer" type="button" data-answer="{$answer['answerid']}">Comment</button>`

Just to run the right javascript function for that answer. @James

Comment: Check the rendered html make sure you are getting a data-id attribute on each button.  It should work unless you have other bugs that I havent noticed.  I assumed the field name of the answer id was "id" - that might be wrong and you might have to change it to the field you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143924/discussion-between-luis-costa-and-james).